# mimic a click on a download link using another click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

`adown` is a link to a file to be downloaded
it works on my page
`btndown` is a button to mimic `adown` click
but simply - doesn't work - nothing happens on `btndown` click
any help

```js
$('#btndown').on('click', function(){
        $('#adown').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id='adown' href='test.html' download>down</a>
<button id='btndown'>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: If the button is in a form, it will try to submit the form. It should be type="button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger the click on the `a` element in order for it to initiate the `download` you need to fire the event on the Element object, not the jQuery object:

```js
$('#btndown').on('click', function() {
  $('#adown')[0].click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="adown" href="test.html" download>down</a>
<button id="btndown">CLICK</button>
```

Note that I would suggest not using this pattern though, as it's very easily broken by both users disabling JS and by browser updates. I would suggest changing the `button` to a duplicate `<a download>` element, styled as necessary if that is the reason behind changing the element type.

Comment: thanks, solved. Problem - click on button is part of a jquery ajax callback function, so I can't see another way